# Writing an executable file with another

Tags: c#, exe, executable

I have this service which is an .exe file, and I have a .exe that installs the service. Would it be possible to run the installer exe > that writes the service exe > then do the other things so you don't have to have 2 .exe files but only 1?

Comment: Instead of creating a installer for your service, you have can use the service exe and use `installUtil` to manually install the service.

Comment: I have an auto installer and I don't want to use a manual install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the service.exe as an EmbeddedResource of your install.exe.

To extract you can do:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\service.exe", Resources.embeddedserviceexe);
}
catch
{
    // ToDo
}
```

If you don't want to add your exe to the project resources (via the resource manager in your project properties), you can just add the exe to you project,  set its properties to EmbeddedResource and then do:

```
try
{             
    using (Stream resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Namespacename.service.exe"))
  {
      using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\service.exe", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < resourceStream.Length; i++)
              fileStream.WriteByte((byte)resourceStream.ReadByte());
       }
    }
 }
 catch
 {
     // ToDo
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

That's like giving birth :)
I would probably have chosen another approach. How about using a packages?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question or explain the alternative suggested.